# A simple elementary inequality (without ABC Thm)

Tags: inequality

I want to solve this following inequality.
$$\sum_{sym } x^5 - 7 \sum _{sym} x^4y + 7 \sum_{sym} x^3 y^2 + 10 \sum_{sym} x^3 yz - 11\sum_{sym} x^2y^2z \ge 0 $$ whenever $ x,y,z \ge 0 $

I do not want to use the ABC Theorem, i.e. I want to solve this problem symmetrically, by using Schur's inequality, Muirhead's inequality, SOS, etc.
I have tried, and solved $$\sum_{sym } x^5 -(2 \sqrt 6 +2 ) \sum _{sym} x^4y + 7 \sum_{sym} x^3 y^2 + 4 \sqrt 6 \sum_{sym} x^3 yz - (6+2 \sqrt 6 )\sum_{sym} x^2y^2z \ge 0 $$ and
$$\sum_{sym } x^5 - 7 \sum _{sym} x^4y + 7.25 \sum_{sym} x^3 y^2 + 10 \sum_{sym} x^3 yz - 11.25\sum_{sym} x^2y^2z \ge 0 $$ 
but this is not enough. Can someone solve this please?

Comment: Use the $uvw$ method. See here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=278791